# Sbt download fails when running assembly on ubuntu

Tags: sbt

I used the following instructions to install sbt:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html

The core commands are:

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

These succeeded.

Then when I try to use `sbt assembly` for the first time the following occurs:

```
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.11!apply-macro.jar (1991ms)

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.11!collections.jar: Invalid TLS padding data (784ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.11!collections.jar: Invalid TLS padding data (784ms)

..

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
download failed: org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.11!collections.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.11!incremental-compiler.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.11!compile.jar
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/stephen/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.11
```

So .. any steps missing to make sbt happy?  I am on ubuntu 14.0.4.1 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was a transient connectivity issue. After waiting some time and re-trying sbt assembly was able to download the missing components and then succeed.