# FIRRTL repository download failed

Tags: scala, ubuntu, jar, download, sbt

I installed **sbt** following this: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html

Now, i'm trying to get **firrtl** set up

https://github.com/ucb-bar/firrtl

But "sbt compile" throws an error:

```
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
    :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :: org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.11!main.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.11!actions.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.11!io.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.11!completion.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.11!collections.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.11!api.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.11!incremental-compiler.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.11!compile.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.11!ivy.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.11!main-settings.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.11!command.jar
    :: org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.11!compiler-interface.jar
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
download failed: org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.11!main.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.11!actions.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.11!io.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.11!completion.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.11!collections.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.11!api.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.11!incremental-compiler.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.11!compile.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.11!ivy.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.11!main-settings.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.11!command.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.11!compiler-interface.jar
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/user/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.11
```

The download failed for some files but i can't figure out why.
The only related post i found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347097/sbt-download-fails-when-running-assembly-on-ubuntu). But i'm not sure if it's a connectivity issue...

Reinstalling and cleaning the whole thing did not help...

I'm working on ubuntu 16.04.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was within the certificates of openjdk-9. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165525/exception-on-download-sun-security-validator-validatorexception-no-trusted-cer) and did the following to solve the failed downloads:

**Uninstall OpenJDK 9**:

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-9-*
```

**Install OpenJDK 8**:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

**Reinstall sbt**: ([Reference](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html))

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

After doing so, i was able to execute

```
sbt compile
```